# How do I get conversion with "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long" error working on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: python, c++, pandas, numpy, anaconda

When running this on Anaconda Python 2.7.12, Pandas 18.1, Windows Server 2012:

```
df['z'] = df['y'].str.replace(' ', '').astype(int)
```

I get this error:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

I do not get this error on MacOS 10.11 or Ubuntu 14.04.  I read from somewhere else that the Windows C++ compiler has a different definition of long than a Unix-like OS.  If so, how do I make this work on Windows?

Additionally, data.txt is only 172 KB in size.  If it helps, data.txt takes this form:

```
x|y
99999917|099999927 9991
99999911|999999979 9994
99999912|999999902 9992
```

Comment: try `.astype('int64')` - on Windows an `int` is always 32 bits.

Comment: That worked.  Make this an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` is interpreted by numpy by as the `np.int_` dtype, which corresponds to a C integer.  On Windows, even on a 64 bit system, this is a 32 bit integer.

So if you need to cast larger values, specify a 64 bit integer using

```
.astype('int64')
```